# error in saving the time using time picker in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i have to save 5 edittext and 1 time picker value.I have created the database class for that.My all edittext values are getting saved but time picker value is not getting saved,Can anyone help me in solving this issue

I have tried a lot,,but struck in saving the time using time picker

My main java class is http://pastebin.com/BKnRcXqu

My database class is http://pastebin.com/DaHJ2fvj

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: For the `TimePicker` you're just getting the `tag` value from that element. How do you expect to obtain the time from this tag?

Answer (score 1):

To get the time from your TimePicker, you can use

```
int time_pick_hour = picker.getCurrentHour();
int time_pick_minute = picker.getCurrentMinute();
```

It will return hours in a 0-23 format.  You can then take these values and put them as you need to in your database.  Seconds cannot be returned from a TimePicker.